# if-then inside a for loop doesn't execute cmds to all array entries

Tags: arrays, bash, loops, if-statement, for-loop

Running the below returns for lines of echoed text, but only the first app from the array actually gets touched:

```
#!/bin/sh

path=/Applications

app[0]="Microsoft Communicator.app"
app[1]="Microsoft Lync.app"
app[2]="Microsoft Messenger.app"
app[3]="Remote Desktop Connection"

IFS=""

for i in ${app[*]}
do
        if [[ -a $path/$app ]];
        then
            chflags hidden $path/$app;
            echo "Hiding $app"
        fi;
done

exit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the loop use $i instead of $app, like below:

```
for i in ${app[*]}
do
        if [[ -a $path/$i ]];
        then
            chflags hidden $path/$i;
            echo "Hiding $i"
        fi;
done
```

Comment: That did it - thanks.  Trying to learn the 'real' way to script.

Comment: @da4 In that case you may find [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) useful. When running your script through it, it said "i appears unused. Verify it or export it."

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the basic problem Artur R. Czechowski pointed out, you really should be double-quoting all variable references (and using `[@]` instead of `[*]`). This is the proper way to handle variables with spaces; setting IFS will sort of work, but can break other things. Also, you don't need semicolons at the end of lines in bash. Here's my suggested rewrite:

```
for i in "${app[@]}"
do
    if [[ -a "$path/$i" ]]  # Double-quotes not strictly needed here, but I consider it a good habit
    then
        chflags hidden "$path/$i"
        echo "Hiding $i"
    fi
done
```